# What is the significance of API versions in Azure DevOps?

Tags: api, azure-devops

I've been using Azure DevOps for the last 2 years and I've noticed how the API version has upgraded from v3 to v6 now (some APIs are still on v3 and some on v5)

But what is the significance of this? While I do not wish to say I've seen all APIs, the ones I have used in my day job dont seem to add anything new with each new major version change.

For example,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

This API to list team projects in an organization is now on V6. If you run this in different versions, the response is the same and from memory, the parameters are still the same. What has improved from the previous iterations and is MS maintaining a change log of this somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Every time a new major version of Azure DevOps Sever gets released, the APIs are versioned to ensure that calling conventions for that specific server keep working:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rest-api-versioning?view=azure-devops

For some APIs this changes nothing to the data shapes or arguments, but there can be changes in others.

The Azure DevOps Rest API documentation provides the docs for every version since TFS 2018 in the docs and you can switch between the different API versions in the table if contents:

[image]

[image]

Versions older than 4.1 are also in the docs, but stored elsewhere due to some technical season.

So, while some docs have remained stable ever since 4.1, they do receive new major versions whenever a new version of Teams Foundation Server / Azure DevOps Server was released. The Projects List API you mentioned likely hasn't changed since API version 1, there haven't been any changes in the way projects are created or stored since forever.

Other APIs have evolved much more aggressively, mostly the ones involving Pipelines, Git  and Artifacts. And there you'll find real differences depending on what version you request.

### Note

Azure DevOps and Azure DevOps server will sometimes behave differently depending on the version you specify. And when you leave out the version the request will use whatever latest version is available. So it's best-practice to specify the version you're expecting on order to ensure Azure DevOps processes and returns the data the way you expect it to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have not seen the API version history in the documentation before. Do note that the links you've provided to view the images are not showing up for me but I did manage to find it in the docs.

I will have a look at the APIs you mentioned and see whats changed but I want to know why some APIs are still in V4 or V5 and some are in V6. If APIs like the ones I mentioned havent changed since V1 and are now in V6, why would different APIs be on different versions? Is it something to do with the backend development dealing with the APIs?

Comment: As you can see in the version table, Azure DevOps server 2020 supports all API versions from 4.1 to 6.0. the people on the Azure DevOps team decide when a version is updated or not. The most important thing to remember is that if your tool/script needs to support older versions of Azure DevOps/TFS, then you'll need to pass in a lower version.

Comment: Donovan Brown explains all of it in this talk: https://youtu.be/zp-HbdZKYOo